# How can I fit a logarithmic model to my data in R? nls and lm functions keep returning linear fit and I don't know why

Tags: r, regression, lm, nls

I need to fit a model to some data `pH ~ DIC`. See data plotted below:

y axis = pH, x axis = DIC (dissolved inorganic carbon)

[image: plot of ph vs dic]

First I ran a linear regression using `lm`, but it seems clear that a non-linear model would be a more accurate fit. I tried a logarithmic function based on the visual distribution of the data points. I've tried using both `lm` and `nls` functions, but when I visualize the fit it's still linear and I don't understand why. Neither do any of my colleagues more experienced in R. This is what it looks like fitted, using a logarithmic function:

[image: plot log ph vs dic]

I used the following code to attempt the nls function:

```
y <- df2$y[!is.na(df2$y)]
x <- df2$x[!is.na(df2$x)]
fit <- nls(y~a+b*log(x), data=df2, start=list(a=8,b=-0.5))
print(fit)

pred <- predict(fit,x, type="response")
plot(df2$x,df2$y, pch = 20)
lines(x, pred, lwd = 3, col = "blue")
```

I also tried using ggplot with nls:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="nls", se=FALSE, formula=y~a+b*log(x),
              method.args=list(start=c(a=8, b=-1)))
```

And using lm with a logarithmic function:

```
plot(x,y)

model <- lm(y~log(x), data=df2)
summary(model)

new_y <- predict(model, newdata=list(x=x))

matlines(x,new_y, lwd=2)
```

All of them return the same outcome (with slightly different aesthetics)

I want to end up with a best fit curve. I don't understand why it's returning a linear best fit when I'm using a logarithmic function.

Comment: Did you try `plot(x, new_y, type = 'c')`.

Comment: Why do you believe these fits are exactly linear in x? If you look at `curve(log(x), xlim = c(1.8, 2.1))` you see that the logarithmic function is close to linear in this range of x values. Your result is not surprising. You might want to change the function for the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered:

`lm` finds the correct relationship between the two vectors (logaritmic) and does a good prediction. However, this cannot be represented using `abline` or `plot(, type="l")`. When I attempt it, here is what I encounter:

```
## dummy data
x <- sample(1:100, 60)
y <- log(x)
## fit the model
fit <- lm(y ~ log(x))
# predict values
pred <- predict(fit)
# plot the predicted values in a line
plot(pred, x, type = "l")
```

[image]

It draws a line between the predicted points. The following is the correct way to draw curves: First, you have to find a function that explains the relationship between your variables. In this case `log`. Then, plot it against `x`:

```
# plot the function (relationship) between values
curve(log, x)
```

[image]

You shoud, however, check the relationship between `y` and `new_y` to make sure the prediction is correct.